# "rm" doesn't accept internal command as a paramter

Tags: bash, command-line, gsettings, rm

Why doesn't this work?

```
rm $(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri  | awk '{gsub("file://","");print $0}')
rm: cannot remove `\'/home/foggy/obrazky/wallpapers/24/Dark_Oxygen_by_Falco101.png\'': No such file or directory
```

Perhaps there is some character that `rm` doesn't accept?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look closely and you'll notice that it has embedded single quotes, which you will have to remove yourself.  I would change the `awk` to a `sed`:

```
rm $(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri |
     sed -e "s/'//g" -e 's,file://,,g')
```

(Although actually I would look at exactly what the unmodified output of `gsettings` looks like first, so as to make something a bit more bulletproof.)

Comment: As noted by mgd in a comment to his answer, this isn't completely correct - filenames _can_ contain single quotes, so stripping all of them out is wrong.

Comment: @Izkata, that (and a number of similar issues) is what I meant by the comment about looking at the actual output and bulletproofing.

Comment: Well, since its purpose is just to delete a wallpaper it is not very important and I can live with possibility that there would be such a file that will not be deleted...

Comment: You are right, but another time it will _not_ be a wall paper. So to strip off the `'` chars correctly you should use `see` like this `sed -e "s|^'file://\(.*\)'$|\1|g"` or maybe easier to read `sed -e "s|^'file://||g" -e "s|'$||"`. Note the `^` matches the beginning of the line and `$` matches the end of the line. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 10):

It looks like you have an extra pair of single quote characters around your filename that need to be stripped off.

Here, I have a file named "hello":

```
$ ls
hello
```

Trying to delete it with extra single quotes like this:

```
$ rm "'hello'"
```

gives exactly the error message you see:

```
rm: cannot remove `\'hello\'': No such file or directory
```

the `\'` before and after the name are single quotes you need to strip off.

EDIT:

In your case (as another answerer has noted) the output of

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri
```

returns a result like:

```
'file:///usr/share/backgrounds/Tie_My_Boat_by_Ray_Garc%C3%ADa.jpg'
```

So you want to strip the leading `'file://` and the ending `'`. This can be done correctly using `sed` like this (using only one expression with a group)

```
sed -e "s|^'file://\(.*\)'$|\1|g"
```

or maybe easier to read (using two simple expressions)

```
sed -e "s|^'file://||g" -e "s|'$||"
```

Please note:

- `^` matches the beginning of the line
- `$` matches the end of the line.
- any character can be used in `sed` to surround the search and replace expressions. Normally, you would use `/` but in this case it is easier to use something else, so I use `|`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for a quick and right answer. It works now. I will write here the result.

Comment: I cannot comment on the answer currently flagged as the correct one, so I will write my comment here. Please be careful _not_ to strip out every single `'`character as suggested but only the ones surrounding your file name (in the rare event that your file name contains a single quote -- seldom but seen).

Answer (score 3):

`gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri` returns a result like:

`'file:///usr/share/backgrounds/Tie_My_Boat_by_Ray_Garc%C3%ADa.jpg'`

Those single-quotes at the ends are your undoing :-)

I'll assume you're using awk for a reason, and give you two simple solutions which strip the quotes before feeding the output of `gsettings` to `awk`:

- `cut -d "'" -f2`
- `tr "'" " "`

Stick them in the middle and you're done, e.g.:

```
rm $(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri |   
`cut -d "'" -f2` | sed -e "s/'//g" -e 's,file://,,g')

rm $(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri |   
`tr "'" " "` | sed -e "s/'//g" -e 's,file://,,g')
```

Comment: Thanks.   It took me a while to find out how to strip the quotes and you have even more solutions :)

Comment: What are the backticks around `cut -d "'" -f2` and `tr "'" " "` for? If they're intended, I'm not sure what those commands are supposed to do. Looking at the markdown of this answer, it looks like they may be typos--block code formatting is achieved in a somewhat unusual way. If they're not intended, then this answer makes sense but fails with a (presumably escaped) `'` in the output of `gsettings`. Then text gets cut off there. See also [the related flaw in the accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135499/rm-doesnt-accept-internal-command-as-a-paramter?rq=1#comment161770_135506).

Answer (score 0):

This would work too (although not particularly secure):

```
eval rm $(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri  | awk '{gsub("file://","");print $0}')
```